# How does the DOM manipulation in this JavaScript code work?

Tags: javascript

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Advanced JavaScript - Lesson 3 - Exercise 21 </title>
  <script>
    const data = [
      {
        from: 'Zach',
        to: 'Tim',
        subject: 'Hello',
        body: 'Nice to meet you Tim. Looking forward to discussing business next week.'
      },
      {
        from: 'Kirsten',
        to: 'Tim',
        subject: 'Car for sale',
        body: 'I saw that you are selling your car. I am intersted.'
      },
      {
        from: 'Jessica',
        to: 'Tim',
        subject: 'Code review',
        body: 'When will you finish the code review? The deadline for our application is next week and we are behind schedule.'
      },
      {
        from: 'Walter',
        to: 'Tim',
        subject: 'Donations',
        body: 'Thank you for your generous donation. Can you please send me your address? We are sending our top 5 donors thank you placards.'
      },
      {
        from: 'Tristain',
        to: 'Tim',
        subject: 'Birthday party',
        body: 'We should plan our sister\'s surprise birthday party soon. Venues tend will start getting booked over the next two weeks.'
      }
    ]
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="emailTableHolder"></div>
  <script>

    // Create table
    const table = document.createElement( 'table' );

    // Create headers
    {
      const headers = [ 'to', 'from', 'subject' ];
      const row = document.createElement( 'tr' );
      headers.forEach( h => {
        const header = document.createElement( 'th' );
        header.appendChild( document.createTextNode( h.charAt( 0 ).toUpperCase() + h.substr( 1 ) ) );
        row.appendChild( header );
      } );
      table.appendChild( row );
    }

    // Create row for each email
    {
      data.forEach( email => {
        const row = document.createElement( 'tr' );
        const to = document.createElement( 'td' );
        const from = document.createElement( 'td' );
        const subject = document.createElement( 'td' );

        to.appendChild( document.createTextNode( email.to ) );
        from.appendChild( document.createTextNode( email.from ) );
        subject.appendChild( document.createTextNode( email.subject ) );

        row.appendChild(to);
        row.appendChild(from);
        row.appendChild(subject);

        table.appendChild( row );
      } );
    }

    // Append table to document
    document.getElementById( 'emailTableHolder' ).appendChild( table );

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I know dom manipulation and all but can't really understand what's actually happening in this piece of code.

Comment: To understand this code snippet create a html table and look at the structure and you will see that the code is laid out to reproduce a table structure how be it in code...

Answer (score 0):

```
<table> ----------------------------------------------------
  <tr> -------------------------------                     |
    <th>                             |                     | 
      <!-- created for each          |                     | 
          item in header array -->   |---> created once for| 
                                     |      the headers    | 
   </th>                             |                     | 
  </tr> ------------------------------                     |
  <tr>  -----------------------------|                     |----> 
                                     |                     |   Created
                                     |                     |   once
    <td>to</td> -------              |                     |
    <td>from</td>     |              |---> created once    |
                      |--> created   |                     |
                      | for each     |                     |
                      |  email       |   for email section | 
    <td>subject</td>--|              |                     | 
  </tr> -----------------------------|                     |
</table> --------------------------------------------------|
```

Table header explained:

```
{
      const headers = [ 'to', 'from', 'subject' ];
      const row = document.createElement( 'tr' ); <!-- create a row to house the headers -->
      headers.forEach( h => {
        const header = document.createElement( 'th' );
        header.appendChild( document.createTextNode( h.charAt( 0 ).toUpperCase() + h.substr( 1 ) ) );
        row.appendChild( header );
      } ); 
      table.appendChild( row );
    } <!-- Create a row and for each headers array item, create a 'th' element append a created text node of the header text (represented by h) and take the first char of that string at position '0' and concatenate it to the substring gotten from position '1'. Now append that to the row and finally to the table itself -->
```

Body of table explained:

```
const to = document.createElement( 'td' ); <!-- for each email create a table 'td' element to hold data -->
to.appendChild( document.createTextNode( email.to ) ); <!-- append a text node of the value 'email.to' to the 'td' -->
row.appendChild(to); <!-- Now append that to the row for this particular email -->
```

Now repeat the above process for the other emails and will produce three columns to hold the to, from, and subject information.