# Table cells appending outside the table row instead of inside

Tags: jquery

The HTML:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr class="warning">
            <th> Date </th>
            <th> Teacher </th>
            <th> Join conference </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="lessons_tbody"></tbody>
</table>
```

Using Jquery 3.2.1, I have the following code:

```
$.each(ev, function(key,lesson) {

        $('<tr class="active">').appendTo('#lessons_tbody');
        $.each(lesson, function(key2, value){
            if(key2=='url')
                $('#lessons_tbody').append('<td><a href="'+value+'"><button class="btn btn-primary">Launch Lesson</button></a></td>');
            else
                $('#lessons_tbody').append('<td>'+value+'</td>');                  
        });

        $('</tr>').appendTo('#lessons_tbody');
});
```

This is the resulting HTML:

```
<tbody id="lessons_tbody">

    <tr class="active"></tr>
        <td>2020-06-23 12:00:00</td>
        <td>Testi Test</td>
        <td><a href="/conference/lesson/47/"><button class="btn btn-primary">Launch Lesson</button></a></td>
</tbody>
```

I need the td cells to be inside the table row elements (...)

EDIT 1 - Json response:

[image: json response]

Comment: I don't see any appendChild to tr of the td element in your script?

Comment: That's the question, I haven't figured out how to do that.

Comment: Are you creating multiple rows or just one?

Comment: Multiple, each with 3 td cells.

Comment: You need to determine how many such rows are going to be created or create a forEach function that does that when ever you need to create a and append td to tr using appendChild see: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62391573/2782188

Comment: Isn't there a way to do that with JQuery instead of straight javascript?

Comment: can you show json response ?

Comment: posted the json , i have 4 rows for this example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `append` your html created in some variable using `+=` and lastly append the same to your `tbody` .

**Demo Code** :

```js
//your response
var ev = [{
  lessonDate: " 2020-08-12 12:40",
  teacher: "abc",
  url: "htp://ww.abc.com"
}, {
  lessonDate: " 2020-09-12 10:40",
  teacher: "abc1",
  url: "htp://ww.abc1.com"
}, {
  lessonDate: "2020-02-12 12:40",
  teacher: "abc2",
  url: "htp://ww.abc2.com"
}];
var html = "";
$.each(ev, function(key, lesson) {
  //append tr in html variable
  html += '<tr class="active">';
  $.each(lesson, function(key2, value) {
    if (key2 == 'url')
      html += '<td><a href="' + value + '"><button class="btn btn-primary">Launch Lesson</button></a></td>';
    else
      html += '<td>' + value + '</td>';

  });
  html += '</tr>';

});
  $("#lessons_tbody").append(html) //append row to tbody
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr class="warning">
      <th> Date </th>
      <th> Teacher </th>
      <th> Join conference </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="lessons_tbody"></tbody>
</table>
```